# If a Chinese person had the last name ”金“, how would that name be pronounced in Korean?

Tags: hanja, names

So Kim, or “金” might be the most common last name in Korea. However, some Chinese people also have the last name Jin/金. To my knowledge, however, they don't seem to be related, as they have different origins. In any case, if that Chinese person were to move to Korea or adopt a Korean name, would they be called Keum or Kim? Or perhaps would they be able to go with either?

Comment: All of readings which you mentioned were borrowed from Chinese languages, in various times. Middle Chinese [金](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/金) *kim* (\*/kˠiɪm/ and other reconstructions) evolved to Modern Mandarin *jīn* /t͡ɕin⁵⁵/. [Palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)) of [k] to [t͡ɕ] was recent change in 18th / 19th century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the original pronunciation (“Jin”) is respected and it’s not read with the Korean Hanja readings (“Kim”) unless it’s a name of a historic person. However, it could be, if he’d like to be called so.

You’d be interested in this video:

- [Areveny — “Peculiarities of Trilingual Names in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean”](https://youtu.be/tqDQjZzBe_I)